# Как сделать сеть с коммутатором L3 в Cisco packet tracer с DHCP?

Tags: cisco, dhcp, cisco-packet-tracer, vlan

Задача сделать сеть состоящую из 2 коммутаторов L2 и одного L3. В сети должны быть vlan 2 и 3, а также DHCP.
Вланы уже настроены. Как настроить DHCP по схеме ниже?
Switch0:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1238 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Switch1:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1238 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Multilayer Switch0:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1341 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

UPD:
Знаю как сделать DHCP но только для коммутатора 2го уровня, но это не подходит для 3го

```
Коммутатор
Создание VLAN'ов
(config)#vlan 2
(config-vlan)#name VLAN2
(config-vlan)#exit
(config)#vlan 3
(config-vlan)#name VLAN3
(config-vlan)#exit
(config)#vlan 4
(config-vlan)#name DHCP
(config-vlan)#exit
Настройка интерфейсов
- FastEthernet 0/1 и 0/2 на VLAN 2
(config)#int range fa0/1-2
(config-if-range)#switchport mode access
(config-if-range)#switchport access v 2
- FastEthernet 0/3 и 0/4 на VLAN 3
(config)#int range fa0/3-4
(config-if-range)#switchport mode access
(config-if-range)#switchport access v 3
- FastEthernet 0/5 на VLAN 4
(config)#int fa 0/5
(config-if)#switchport mode access
(config-if)#switchport access v 4
- FastEthernet 0/6 на VLAN 2, 3 и 4 (trunk-порт)
(config)#int fa0/6
(config-if)#switchport mode trunk
(config-if)#switchport trunk allowed v 2,3,4
(config-if)#end

Маршрутизатор
Поднятие интерфейса, соединённого с коммутатором
(config)#int gi0/0
(config-if)#no shutdown 
Создание сабинтерфейсов
- для VLAN 2
(config)#int gi0/0.2
(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 2
(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
(config-subif)#no shutdown
- для VLAN 3
(config)#int gi0/0.3
(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 3
(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
(config-subif)#no shutdown
- для VLAN 4 (DHCP-сервер)
(config)#int gi0/0.4
(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 4
(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.4.1 255.255.255.0
(config-subif)#no shutdown

Далее идёт настройка DHCP-сервера (задание IP-адреса, маски, адреса шлюза, а также настройка DHCP во вкладке Services).
А потом для маршрутизатора настраивается
Перенаправление запроса на DHCP с маршрутизатора на DHCP-сервер
- для VLAN 2
(config)#int gi0/0.2
(config-subif)#ip helper-address 192.168.4.2 - запрос на DHCP перенаправляется на DHCP-сервер (указан его IP)
- для VLAN 3
(config)#int gi0/0.3
(config-subif)#ip helper-address 192.168.4.2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На L3 свитче создать интерфейс vlan2, сконфигурировать на нём IP адрес, например, 10.0.2.1/24. И далее по [инструкции](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1574301&seqNum=5) сконфигурировать пул.
Проделать тоже самое для vlan3,создать интерфейс vlan3, сконфигурировать на нём IP адрес, например, 10.0.3.1/24 и таже создать ещё один DHCP пул по инструкции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по схеме, с применением сервера необходимо. Как можно настроить с сервером?

Comment: Вопрос дополнил. Нашел способ но он работает для 2го уровня коммутатора. Не совсем понимаю как можно тот способ применить к 3му уровня коммутатора.

Comment: L3 свитч тут какую роль играет? А то ещё роутер есть.

Comment: пардон. я не внимательно посмотрел на топологию. не обратил внимание, что сервер DHCP внешний